# Alternate of getCurrentControl in ms crm 2015

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a requirement to get the name of the focused tab & section. 
It seems the method getCurrentControl was deprecated after MS CRM 2013 R2 update.

Is there any other method or way to get the name of current focused tab & section.

Reason: I have a html web resource which I want to put it in three different sections & this web resource updates three different attributes based on the inputs from the web resource but I want to use only that html web resource in all three sections & just based on the section name I will update individual attributes.

Please, let me know how can I use any OOTB CRM JavaScript methods?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[The "proper" way is using the "Custom parameter(data)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327945.aspx)

You can pass a parameter to the each "instance" of the web resource, and check it from inside to know which is which.

A positive side-effect is that your code can avoid snooping outside of the iframe.

Comment: Wow.. nice hack.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: But when the page will load then all the sections will call but I need the name of the section when user will do any activity on that section. I am bit lost here on how the parameter will help to find which section user is working on now?